# How to access nested values in JSON response as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, response

Using `const token = response.json().token;` I am able to get the following JSON:

```
{
    "token": "*********",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "User",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 1,
                "role_id": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to access the names within the roles as an array.

Comment: `response.json().roles[0].name`?

Comment: Do it the same way every other person who asks this question does it... search and you will find. I am also highly confused how you can manage to access `token` but can't work out how to access anything else. Seriously, this isn't a joke, I literally cannot comprehend how a person cannot work it out

Comment: What is `response`? In what environment do you want to do this? Do you want to do it in JavaScript, or some other language?

Comment: @chepner thanks, there can be multiple number of arrays. if I use index [0] it grabs only name in the first array. How can I do without using index

Comment: Am I to understand you wish to get a list of names from the roles in the response, while discarding the rest of the data? If so, this might help you a lot:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Why have you decided not to answer the questions above?

Comment: Based on his edit history, it would appear he's using Javascript, specifically ES6. Based on that information and that my assumptions about what he wanted appeared to be correct, I will edit the question to accurately reflect that.

Comment: @Ketzak: We still have no idea what `response` is, but more it's just...why post a question if he/she isn't going to bother to respond to fundamental queries for more information from people trying to help?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I totally agree with you. It's just a common courtesy. I've spent a lot of time working in tech support, and as a programming lab assistant, having to intuit what people "really" want when they ask things, so I figured I'd shoot in the dark on this one based on what I'd gleaned.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder json response that I'm getting. I'm sorry for not answering your question in time

Comment: @yer: That doesn't answer the question at all. But never mind, if Ketzak's solution works for you, great.

Comment: @musefan you can wish not to answer if you don't like my question. But you can't expect all people make things work if you do. I appreciate you taking time to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the array of roles, assuming you're using a traditional response object, you can just access it the way other users have stated:

```
var roles = response.json().roles
```

As I reread the question and comments, I get the idea that the user wants to access the names within the roles as as list. Assuming so, the map function will do this nicely:

```
// Assuming we store response in "data"
var data = response.json();
var names = data.roles.map(function(role){return role.name});
console.log(names);
// Then "names" will look like ["User",...]
```

In a nutshell, map will walk the array it's called against and run the provided function against it, with the first argument being the current value it sees in the array. This function can be defined on the fly as above, or predefined and passed if the logic is complex or reused.

This is a very common use for Map, and its sibling, Reduce. Both are often used for distilling complex, variable-length data down to a simpler form.

Map documentiation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

**Update:** It would appear the original question was asked regarding ES6, so here's the "proper" ES6 version with proper declarations and arrow funcs:

```
// Assuming we store response in "data"
const data = response.json();
const names = data.roles.map(role => role.name);
console.log(names);
// Then "names" will look like ["User",...]
```

Comment: thanks a ton. this is what I'm actually looking for.